# Django Gateway Timeout running on IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, server, fastcgi

I am running a Django app on a windows 10 machine with IIS web server. The application based on user command starts a selenium instance and try to collect some data from third party sites. The problem is that when the collecting data gets long time, actually more than 30s i get a 504 Gateway Timeout at the client. I searched across the web and find some parameters to set including:

```
ARR timeout
application pool idle timeout
Default website Connection timeout
```

adding following parameters to the applicationHost.config file:

```
<application fullPath="..." arguments="...\wfastcgi.py" signalBeforeTerminateSeconds="60" idleTimeout="900" activityTimeout="180" requestTimeout="10000" />
```

But, any of them helped and the 504 again on 30s.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue you can follow the below steps:

1)open iis manager.

2)select your Django site (not default site)

3)click on advance setting from the action pane.

4)increase the connection time out value as per your requirement.

[image]

Note: First check that when you use the site without hosting in iis how much time it will take and what is the site of the data which is transferred.