# Django: Accessing database on different server: "The fastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout"

Tags: django, fastcgi

I have deployed a django application on Windows Server 2012. This application accesses a database on a different server. When I try to load it, it says

> The fastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout.

How can I solve this?

Comment: For me, this happens when I try to upload a video with the upload form, so I created this bounty.

Comment: @xralf the activityTimeout is low, so the uploading of video exceeds the timeout.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902554/fastcgi-process-exceeded-configured-activity-timeout

Answer (score 2):

By default the activity timeout is set to 30 secs. you need to increase it

**Step 1 :** Click on the server name in IIS,

**Step 2 :** Select **FastCGI Settings**

**Step 3 :** Click the FastCGI application that is used. Under **Process Model**
increase the **Activity Timeout** to a higher value and restart the server

If the uploaded file is large and you encounter request timeout issue, look into this : [Django on IIS: Debugging IIS Error due to FastCGI request timeout on large file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641193/django-on-iis-debugging-iis-error-due-to-fastcgi-request-timeout-on-large-file).

Based on your web.config file, i have added a fastcgi section, please try the below configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 
  <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" />
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="100485760" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="3600" maxQueryStringLength="18192" />
</system.web>
  <system.webServer>
  <fastCgi>
     <application fullPath="C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
         activityTimeout="3600"
         requestTimeout="604800">
     </application>
    </fastCgi>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI" 
      path="*" 
      verb="*" 
      modules="FastCgiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
      resourceType="Unspecified" 
      requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
 
  <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
 
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pd_videowebapp" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="pd_videowebapp.wsgi.application" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="pd_videowebapp.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a feeling that I have Activity timeout 180 s and maximum allowed content length 2147483648 bytes. Though, I haven't tried the other settings yet, so I will try tomorrow morning.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't helped.

Comment: this is how you increase the ActivityTimeout. have you tried by increasing the value? may be try with a larger value like 1200 (20 mins)

Comment: I can try it, but the video file I want to upload is quite small and works quickly when use `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Would it help to send you my web.config?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/P11zu3hR) is it.

Comment: @xralf updated the answer. added fastcgi configuration to you config file , please check if it works

Comment: It didn't helped. I'm still waiting about 5 minutes when uploading a small video file.

Comment: @xralf the solution is for solving the activityTimeout. if you are facing issue with the time taken to upload a file, i guess it is a separate question. might be a network or firewall issue. check this : https://serverfault.com/questions/933901/iis-slow-file-upload

Comment: But the upload of a video didn't finished.

Comment: If the file upload is not finished, that is a different problem. You need to check why is it uploading slow or ask a new question. The original question is getting activityTimeout, the above solution will solve it. With the above solution you can keep a high activityTimeout, so that it will not throw any errors until then. Try with any other small files or search for fastcgi low upload speed

Comment: But the error is the same. I only didn't want to wait so long for the result.

Comment: For anyone having issues with the beginning of Step 3 (clicking on the FastCGI application), I offer this tip: you literally have to find the specific python.exe within whatever virtual directory that you [should be] using and click on that.

I didn't realize this at first and just edited web.config instead. That didn't do anything...